# Parse an IP address string into segments with regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

*This question has been updated to improve its rating*

Language Environment:
C#

Desired Outcome:

- Use regular expressions to parse an IP address from a string.
- Use `Regex.Split()` to parse an IP address into individual segments and store them as individual string objects in an array.

Starting with:

```
"IP=100.5.10.15"
```

Get to a `string[] ipAdrSegments` populated with:

```
ipSeg0 = "100"
ipSeg1 = "5"
ipSeg2 = "10"
ipSeg3 = "15"
```

Comment: And what have you tried in order to solve this by yourself?  Questions that do not show any effort are viewed as being very lazy and will more likely than not get closed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have a look around. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to get an idea of the kind of questions that are likely to get an answer here. Your question does not describe the work you have done so far yourself. Try solving the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string ip = "100.5.10.15";
string[] parts = ip.Split('.');
```

Comment: What is it with developers and always wanting to use RegEx for simple string functions?

Comment: @Tim lol, but if you create a regex with capturing group then a loop to iterate over all the capturing groups, grab its content and push it into an array can achieve the same goal! lol. I don't understand the downvoter

Comment: Simple and clear solution.  It works, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use `IPAddress.Parse` and `IPAddress.TryParse` methods to parse IP address string.

The reason is described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/486788/why-does-pinging-192-168-072-only-2-dots-return-a-response-from-192-168-0-58). String representation of IPv4 address is rather more complicated than 4 numbers separated by dot symbol. For example, the following strings are correct representations of the same IP address:

> 74.125.226.4  (dotted decimal)
>
> 1249763844  (flat decimal)
>
> 0112.0175.0342.0004  (dotted octal)
>
> 011237361004  (flat octal)
>
> 0x4A.0x7D.0xE2.0x04  (dotted hex)
>
> 0x4A7DE204  (flat hex)
>
> 74.0175.0xe2.4  (ಠ_ಠ)

In case if you still want to parse IP addresses manually and allow using only 4-number dotted decimal representation, I suggest you to use something like this:

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

*Note: this regex is still not correct because it allows leading zeros (014.2.3.4)*

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for pointing to `System.Net.IPAddress`.